# MaskedTextBox in DataGridView column cells

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, maskedtextbox

How do you add a [`MaskedTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) in every cell in a column of the [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) in VB.NET?

A very good C# example is *[DataGridViewColumn Hosting MaskedTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox)*, but how do I do it in VB.NET?

Comment: Try [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: how do i solve this problem `Class 'MaskedTextBoxEditingControl' must implement 'Property EditingControlDataGridView() As DataGridView' for interface 'System.Windows.Forms.IDataGridViewEditingControl'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.`

Comment: VB.Net uses the `Implements` keyword for interface elements, so you have to add it to the property.

Comment: could you tell me how... i'm new to vb.net... and sorry if that was too much trouble.. oh and btw this is the line that gives that error `Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl`

Comment: i converted the code but most of the psrt doesnot work it would be better if you gave me a vb.net `DataGridViewMaskedTextBoxColumn` tutorial or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a VB.NET implementation for the `MaskEditColumn` in the below link. But I am not sure whether it is VB.NET version of [The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project) implementation. You could check this out.

*[MaskEditColumn for DataGridView](http://www.vb-tips.com/MaskedEditColumn.aspx)*